# .htaccess url rewrite for specific page

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I would need help rewriting a php url. The current url is

> https://www.websitename.com/testi**o.php?name_of_link.html**

and i like be

> https://www.websitename.com/**testi/name_of_link.html**

in short **o.php?** are transformed into **/**

my .htaccess file is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#rewrite pages from php top html and sitemap from php to xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: That query string should be `link=name_of_link.html`. I suspect this also is running into `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$`, is that correct? Please describe the issue a bit more

Comment: You can try this one: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ $1o.php?$2 [L]`